# How do i convert a C++ function in c# function

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I am working on Amibroker C# plugin project. Amibroker SDK is written in C++ but, I am using a C# plugin which does exactly what Amibroker C++ does [C# Plugin link](http://amibroker.codeplex.com/)

Everything in C# plugin works just fine except one function which is written in c++ this way:

```
PLUGINAPI struct RecentInfo* GetRecentInfo(LPCTSTR ticker)
{
   //Process & return RecentInfo* (RecentInfo is a structure)
}
```

In C# standard plugin it has been converted this way

```
public RecentInfo GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return RecentInfo
}
```

Unfortunately, Amibroker application crashes with this wrong conversion. So I did try to convert it my way to get Amibroker App working, but failed multiple times
This is what i have tried so far:

### Attemp 1:

```
unsafe public RecentInfo* GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return RecentInfo* (RecentInfo structure is declared as unsafe)
}
```

### Impact:

Amibroker app does not load

### Attemp 2:

```
public IntPtr GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Process & Return Pointer using Marshal.StructureToPtr
}
```

### Impact:

Amibroker app does not load

### Attemp 3:

```
public void GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
    //Useless becoz no return type
}
```

### Impact:

Amibroker loads & does call function correctly but how do return a structure pointer

So, I am scratching my head to find out the exact conversion of C++ function in C#

Comment: Did you try using ref RecentInfo?

Comment: public ref RecentInfo GetRecentInfo(string ticker) //c# doesnot allow

Comment: I meant - If you are allowed to change the signature of the GetRecentInfo, then allocate memory for RecentInfo structure from the calling method and then pass it as a parameter to GetRecentInfo method as reference.

Answer (score 2):

If it is fully written in c# then  , this  is pretty well ,think there is problem in implementation not in calling

```
public RecentInfo GetRecentInfo(string ticker)
{
      RecentInfo rc;
    //Process & Return RecentInfo
      return rc;
}
```

or this , (you can use ref too)

```
public void GetRecentInfo(string ticker,out RecentInfo rc )
{
rc=new RecentInfo();
....process

 return ;
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of Amibroker. But what is crash report or exception. What it says? And Is it fully written c# or still have calls to c++?

Comment: Crash report says "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Comment: on msdn : An access violation occurs in unmanaged or unsafe code when the code attempts to read or write to memory that has not been allocated, or to which it does not have access. SO either it calls some unmanaged functions or unsafe c# code . Check inside of function

Comment: also check for null Reference . maybe you forgot to initialize